# Sublime Text: Replace with fixed width field(using regex)

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

Is there a way to replace an expression(a line containing multiple fields) found through regex, with fields in a fixed width format in sublime text?

For instance, I have several lines of text like:

```
CS 210         Data Structures Laboratory                     (0-0-3-3)
CS 221                  Digital Design             (3-0-0-6)
CS 241     System Software Laboratory               (0-0-3-3)
CS 203          Formal Languages and Automata Theory         (3-0-0-6)
```

I need to replace them by something like this:

```
CS 210          Data Structures Laboratory                 (0-0-3-3)
CS 221          Digital Design                             (3-0-0-6)
CS 241          System Software Laboratory                 (0-0-3-3)
CS 203          Formal Languages and Automata Theory       (3-0-0-6)
```

The fields in each line can be obtained separately by the regex search:

```
([A-Z]{2} +[\d]{3}) +((?: *\-* *\w+)+) +([\(\-\d\)]{9})
```

($1: course no., $2: course name, $3: credit system)
In the replace expression, being able to set fixed width for each capture group will solve the problem.

Comment: Can't you just change the order of the fields, so thtat the course name is the last field? Example: `CS 210          (0-0-3-3)          Data Structures Laboratory`

Comment: @sergioFC well, you are right here.. but that works only in this particular example. there could be more columns with variable length.Anyway, nice idea.. :)

Comment: I think this can't be done using only regex

Answer (score 0):

1. find more than two consecutive spaces with regex  `\s{2,}` and replace it with other field separators. i.e. Pipe(|)
2. now you have each field separated with a pipe, which is easy to managable.